# Why is this Mandelbrot set's implementation infeasible: takes a massive amount of time to do?

Tags: complex, code-review, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy, fractals

The Mandelbrot set is defined by complex numbers such as $z=z^2+c$ where $z_0=0$ for the initial point and $c\in\mathbb C$. The numbers grow very fast in the iteration.

```
z = 0; n = 0; l = {0};
While[n < 9, c = 1 + I; l = Join[l, {z}]; z = z^2 + c; n++];l
```

If `n` is very large, the numbers become too large and impossible to calculate in practical time limits. I don't know what it would look after long time but doubting whether it would look like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egsqa.png).

**What is wrong with this implementation? Why does it take so long time to calculate?**

Comment: somewhat relevant discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8590583#8590583)

Comment: It takes a long time to calculate because you are doing exact arithmetic with very large numbers. You will want to use machine precision for computing fractals in any reasonable time. More importantly, why are you computing the sequence for an escaping point? I think you need to read more and code less until you have a basic understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SimonWoods is there some command to make Mathematica use only Machine-precision numbers?

Comment: A useful introduction http://www.wikihow.com/Plot-the-Mandelbrot-Set-By-Hand

Comment: Add a decimal point to the numbers you use, or use N.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What is wrong: a) you're using exact arithmetic. b) You keep iterating even if the point seems to be escaping.

Try this

```
ClearAll@prodOrb;
prodOrb[c_, maxIters_: 100, escapeRadius_: 1] := 
 NestWhileList[#^2 + c &,
  0.,
  Abs[#] < escapeRadius &,
  1,
  maxIters
  ]

prodOrb[0. + 10. I]
prodOrb[0. + .1 I]
```

(if you don't need the entire list but only the final point, replace `NestWhileList` by `NestWhile`).

Here, I use approximate numbers by using `0.` rather than `0`. See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html) tutorial for more.

EDIT: Since we're doing interactive manipulation:

```
ClearAll[mnd];
mnd = Compile[{{maxiter, _Integer}, {zinit, _Complex}, {dt, _Real}},
   Module[{z, c, iters},
    Table[
     z = zinit;
     c = cr + I*ci;
     iters = 0.;
     While[(iters < maxiter) && (Abs@z < 2),
      iters++;
      z = z^2 + c
      ];
     Sqrt[iters/maxiter],
     {cr, -2, 2, dt}, {ci, -2, 2, dt}
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];


Manipulate[
 lst = mnd[100, {1., 1.*I}.p/500, .01];
 ArrayPlot[Abs@lst],
 {{p, {250, 250}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clicking around changes the fractal. Note the magic numbers sprinkled throughout the code. Why? Because `ListContourPlot` is way too slow, so that using the coords of the clicked point ended up being too much of a waste of time (and my coffee break is over).

EDIT2:
So much for the break being over. Here we have the Mandelbrot set being blown away by strong winds:

```
tbl = Table[
  lst = mnd[100, (1 + 1.*I)*p/500, .01];
  ArrayPlot[Abs@lst],
  {p, 0, 500, 10}
  ];

ListAnimate[tbl]
```

[image: Withering mandelbrot]

And see, here it is, sliding off the table while being melted:

```
tbl2 = Table[
   mnd[100, (1 + 1.*I)*p/500, .05] // Abs // 
    ListPlot3D[#, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
      ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Axes -> False, 
      Boxed -> False, 
      ViewVertical -> {0, (p/500), Sqrt[1 - (p/500)^2]}] &,
   {p, 0, 500, 25}
   ];
```

(this is very slow, because `ListPlot3D` is very slow)

[image]

Maximal silliness has now been achieved. Or has it?

Comment: why do you the dot "0." in the term *"NestWhileList[#^2+c &,0.,Abs[$]<escapeRadius&,"* and not "0"?

Comment: @hhh: "0" is an exact number. "0." is a machine-precision number, and calculations with machine-precision numbers are much faster.

Comment: @nikie is correct; press F1 to bring up the help centre, then paste `tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults` into the top bar to see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html) tutorial.

Comment: After seeing the chat you referred to, +1 for patience.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Indeed (and more, if you include the previous day)!

Comment: very nice; I feel I ought to delete my derivative answer now that you've started illustrating your own answer so well ... (But I don't think I will... :)

Comment: @cormullion don't bother, I am just doing it out of boredom. all our answers are useless to the OP; what they need to do is learn basic mathematica syntax and complex numbers. But since everybody else is after *my upvotes*, well... :)

Answer (score 17):

Just a bit of fun with @acl's code:

```
ArrayPlot[Table[
  NestWhile[#^2 - (0. - 1 I) & , r + i I, Abs[#] < 2.0 &, 1, 10],
  {r, -2, 2, 0.005},
  {i, -2, 2, 0.005}]]
```

[image: fractal]

Comment: +1 I swear I didn't even know that `ArrayPlot` accepted complex values!

Comment: Hehe.. look at what you implemented and what the OP was asking :-) And don't take my implementation as reference, because I was only looking at yours and did it as wrong. Let's see who realizes it.

Comment: @halirutan What *was* the OP asking?

Comment: @halirutan well, i wasn't really answering the OP - just thought I'd post a nice picture I made while tinkering with acl's code (a cast silver lightning bolt wrapped in an infinite amount of black velvet).

Comment: Sweet! Can it dance? Perhaps like [the eyes](http://i.imgur.com/1faEnTz.gif)? :D

Comment: @rm-rf it can dance, yes. see my answer!

Comment: @rm-rf (or, well, sort of fall gracefully anyway)

Answer (score 15):

With a compiled version you get it so fast, that you can manipulate it in real time.

```
fc = Compile[{{in, _Complex, 0}, {c, _Complex, 0}},
   Module[{iter = 0, max = 10, z = in},
    While[iter++ < max,
     If[Abs[z = z^2 + c] > 2.0,
      Break[]
      ]
     ];
    {Abs[z], iter}
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];

data = Table[i + I j, {j, -2, 2, .01}, {i, -2, 2, .01}];

Manipulate[ImageAdjust[Image[fc[data, cx + I cy]]],
 {cx, -.5, .5},
 {cy, -.5, .5}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And since my iteration does calculate a Julia set instead of the Mandelbrot set, let's fix this

```
fc = Compile[{{c, _Complex, 0}},
   Module[{iter = 0, max = 100, z = 0 + 0 I},
    While[iter++ < max,
     If[Abs[z = z^2 + c] > 2.0,
      Break[]
      ]
     ];
    {Log[iter], Abs[z]}
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];

data = Table[i + I j, {j, -2, 2, 4/1023.}, {i, -2, 2, 4/1023.}];
ImageAdjust[Image[fc[data]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To calculate this 1024x1024 image, it **took only 0.2 seconds** on my machine here. I wouldn't consider this slow.

Comment: Put `RuntimeOptions->"Speed"` in my code and watch yourself ;-)

Comment: @chyanog On my machine, the timing is 0.169407 for your method and 0.163131 for my one with option "Speed".

Comment: Here chyanog's is about three times faster, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed" included: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RtHDG.png  OS X, clang-425.0.27

Comment: @chyanog Actually both run in the same amount of time.  The mistake I made was to use your `data` with halirutan's function.  Maybe you made the same mistake.  Both run in about 0.17 seconds here.

Answer (score 9):

As @acl mentioned in chat, your question really indicates that you should read some fundamental sources.  Two that I'd recommend are:

- [A First Course in Chaotic Dynamical Systems](http://www.westviewpress.com/book.php?isbn=0201554062) by Bob Devaney for a good overview of the mathematical theory.
- [Mathematica in Action](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387753664) by Stan Wagon, specifically Chapter 11, for a more condensed overview but with specific Mathematica code.

Note that the second reference, which I happen to have written largely avoids `Compile` and the speediest of speedy tricks presented by the other answers here in favor of simpler code.  This is probably better, if your objective is to learn the basics of the material.

Comment: +1 I agree that avoiding C code is important here. I think all the other answers (including mine, which started out as a bit of a joke and now essentially parodies how mma.se works) are just noise, and do not help hhh to learn what they need to learn. Yours is probably the most useful answer. Lacking graphics as it does, though, it'll get less upvotes!

Comment: @acl Thanks!  I can live without the upvotes; I tend to be conservative with mine, anyway.

Comment: they are practically useful in that the visibility of upvoted answers increases. However, in this particular case, the question really is framed in too specific terms (it's really 1. how do I use floating-point numbers 2. what's wrong with my algorithm to obtain a mandelbrot set), so unlikely to be useful to future visitors with similar questions. Well maybe it'll be useful to people who are new to complex numbers and fractals, to whom your answer is the only useful one...

Comment: Where can you find the notebooks for the book Mathematica in Action by Stan Wagon?

Comment: @hhh They come with the book! An antiquated concept, I know.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[mandel];
mandel =
  Compile[{{A, _Real, 1}, {maxIt, _Real}},
   Module[{i = 0, re = 0., im = 0., temp, x = A[[1]], y = A[[2]]},
    While[i++ < maxIt && re^2 + im^2 <= 4,
     temp = re^2 - im^2 + x;
     im = 2 re im + y;
     re = temp;
     ];
    {Log[i], Sqrt[re^2 + im^2]}
    ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];

t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
data = mandel[Table[{i, j}, {j, -2, 2, 4/1023.}, {i, -2, 2, 4/1023.}], 100];
Image@Rescale@data
AbsoluteTime[] - t1
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In *Mathematica* 10.0:

```
    MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2 - I, 1 + I}]
```

(Admittedly, this doesn't address what's wrong with the code in the original question, but if you just want to get a Mandelbrot set plot, surely a built-in function is likely to be reasonably efficient.)