# How to understand the usage of parameters of Image?

Tags: color, image

Normally,we use `Image[RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 3}]]` or use `Image[RandomReal[1, {3, 4}]]` to generate a image.

But in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21714/why-is-this-mandelbrot-sets-implementation-infeasible-takes-a-massive-amount-o/21722#21722)(The image is very cool!),he use `Image[RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 2}]]` structure to generate a Image.

```
data = RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 2}];
Image@data
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
data == ImageData[Image[data]]
```

> True

And then I try

```
Multicolumn[Table[Image[RandomReal[1, {3, 4, i}]], {i, 2, 101}]]
```

I get

> [image]

You can see with the increase of variable `i`,the image is more like a deep color.So strange...

```
data = RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 100}];
data == ImageData[Image[data]]
(*Amazing,it is a color Image,but the length of a pixel is 100!!!*)
```

> True

So how to interpreter the usage of parameters of Image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the theory of this, but if you convert the "two channel" color to RGB you find you always get a color with one of the three components zero:

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose[
  Table[ImageData[
     ColorConvert[Image[{{ {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}}], "RGB"]][[1, 1]],
   {t, 0, Pi/2, .01}]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, DataRange -> {0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

here is a map of the full color space..

```
Image[Table[ {i, j}/100, {i, 0, 100}, {j, 0, 100}]]
```

[image]

or looking beyond the range 0-1 :

```
Image[Table[ {i, j}, {i, -3, 3, .002}, {j, -3, 3, .002}]]
```

[image]

the circles represent `Norm[{c1,c2}]== n Sqrt[2]`

Answer (score 5):

If the data is 2D, then each row is taken as one row of pixels, whose gray level is given by one value

```
white = 1; black = 0; gray = 0.5;
data = {{white, black, gray},
        { gray, white, black},
        {white, gray, black}};
r = Image[data]
```

Since data is 2D, then the image will have 9 pixels, with 3 rows and 3 columns, each pixel value is gray level given as above

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the data is 3D, and if each entry contains 3 numbers, then they are interpreted as RGB value of each pixel. So using the same data as above, but making it 3D, we get one row with only 3 pixels now

```
 Image[{data}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First pixel above has color RBG `{1,0,.5}` and second pixel has `{.5,1,0}` and third pixel has color RGB `{1,.5,0}`

Now if the data is 3D, but each element do not have 3 numbers in it, but only 2 or 4, 5, etc... numbers, as in your example, then Mathematica interpret these as "equally spaced hues"

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So now

```
data = {{white, black},{ gray, white},{white, gray}};
Image[{data}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In your example, data is 3D, but each entry has only 2 numbers. So it falls into the above case.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your data `data = RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 2}]` has 3 rows and 4 columns. But has 2 numbers in each entry of each row.

To make it RGB, then use `data = RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 3}]`

So this is RGB

```
data = RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 3}];
Image[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is Hue

```
data = RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 2}];
Image[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you,but what is equally spaced hues?HSV has three parameter,but here we only have two,they don't match

Comment: @partida I am not a color theory specialist, I just took what Mathematica help page said as you can see. May be this page can shed light on what "equally spaced hue" actually mean.  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue)

Answer (score 4):

2-channel Image

```
Image[Sqrt[2] {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}]

Hue[#/2] & /@ Range[2]
```

can be expressed as `Hue` .

```
Table[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2, .05}, {y, -2, 2, .05}] // Image
```

and

```
mod[x_, y_] := If[# == 0, y, #] &@Mod[x, y];
Table[If[x == y == 0, Black, 
   Hue[3/Pi ArcTan[y, x], 1, mod[Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/2], 1]]], {x, -2, 
   2, .05}, {y, -2, 2, .05}] // Image
```

behave similarly

[image: 2-Channel Image]

Multichannel Image

```
ImageAssemble[
 Table[ColorConvert[Image[Table[n IdentityMatrix[m], {n, 0, 4, .1}]], 
   "RGB"], {m, 10}]]
```

can be expressed as `RGBColor` .

[image: n-Channel Image]

4-channel Image:

```
t = RandomReal[Ceiling[4/3], {4}];
{Image[{{t}}], Image@RGBColor[#, (#2 + #3)/2, #4] & @@ t}
```

5-channel Image:

```
t = RandomReal[Ceiling[5/3], {5}];
{Image[{{t}}], Image@RGBColor[#, (#2 + #3)/2, (#4 + #5)/2] & @@ t}
```

6-channel Image:

```
t = RandomReal[Ceiling[6/3], {6}];
{Image[{{t}}], 
 Image@RGBColor[(#1 + #2)/2, (#3 + #4)/2, (#5 + #6)/2] & @@ t}
```

10-channel Image:

```
{Image[{{#}}], 
   Module[{l = Length[#], r, g}, If[l < 3, Abort[]]; 
    g = Ceiling[l/3];
    r = If[3 g == l, g, g - 1];
    RGBColor @@ (Mean /@ {#[[;; r]], #[[r + 1 ;; 
            r + g]], #[[r + g + 1 ;; l]]}) // Image]} &[
 RandomReal[1, {10}]]
```