# MathLink with Shaw's Complex Analysis with Mathematica

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I purchased (some time ago) a copy of William Shaw's Complex Analysis with Mathematica, published in 2006. He uses MathLink (something I've never done before) to speed up a Mandelbrot application. Here is his template file, named `mandel.tm`.

```
:Begin:
:Function:   fractalml
:Pattern: FractalML[a_?NumberQ,b_?NumberQ,{{c_?NumberQ,d_?NumberQ},{e_?NumberQ,f_?NumberQ}},g_Integer] 
:Arguments:  { N[a],N[b],N[c],N[d],N[e],N[f],g }
:ArgumentTypes: { Real,Real,Real,Real,Real,Real,Integer}
:ReturnType:   Manual
:End:
```

And here is his c-code, named `mandel.c`.

```c
#include "mathlink.h"

void fractalml(double x0,double y0, double xmin, double xmax, double ymin, double ymax, int divs)
{
  double x, y, dist, xadd, yadd, temp;
  int xco, yco, counts;

  MLPutFunction(stdlink,"List",divs);

  for(yco = 0; yco <divs; yco++){
  yadd = ymin + (ymax-ymin)*yco/(divs-1.0);
  MLPutFunction(stdlink,"List",divs);

  for(xco = 0; xco <divs ; xco++){

  x = x0;
  y = y0;
  xadd = xmin + (xmax-xmin)*xco/(divs-1.0);

  dist = x0*x0+y0*y0;
  for(counts = 0; counts<100 && dist < 10000; counts++){
  temp = x*x-y*y+xadd;
  y = 2*x*y+yadd;
  x = temp;
  dist = x*x+y*y;
  }
  MLPutInteger(stdlink,counts);
  }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
return MLMain(argc, argv);
}
```

There is another file (I think it is the compiled file of mandel.c?) named mandel in his folder binMacOSX. All of the files that I have mentioned are included on a CD with his book. I copied his cd files to my MacBook pro (Sierra OS X and Mathematica 11.1.1), then I followed Shaw's first instruction as follows:

```
SetDirectory["/Users/davidarnold/Documents/Mathematica/books/WilliamTShaw/ComplexAnalysis/MathLink/binMacOSX"]
```

Then I tried his second instruction:

```
Install["mandel"]
```

After about three minutes I had to abort. It did not install.

Again, I've never tried to do something like this before, so are there suggestions that might work with his code?

Thanks.

Comment: This does not directly answer the question, but if the book has equivalent WL code you might try redefining it to use `Compile` with the target language set to "C".

Comment: [Here's a Mandelbrot implementation with Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21722/12). It may very well be faster than the MathLink program above.

Answer (score 2):

The C code needs to be compiled before it can be used.  If the code came with a pre-compiled binary, it may still not work.  Macs used a different architecture back in 2006.

To compile the code, first you need a supported C compiler. On a Mac:

- Install XCode from the Mac App Store
- From a terminal, run `xcode-select --install`

Test that the compiler works in Mathematica, like this:

```
<<CCompilerDriver`
CCompilers[]
```

It should list Clang.

Now [`SetDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDirectory.html) to where `mandel.tm` and `mandel.c` are and use

```
<<CCompilerDriver`
CreateExecutable[{"mandel.tm", "mandel.c"}, "mandel", "TargetDirectory" -> "."]
```

This will create an executable named `mandel` in the same directory.  You can use it with [`Install`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Install.html):

```
Install["mandel"]
```

---

Above I showed the automated method to compile.  A step by step guide for manual compilation is here:

- [WSTP developer guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-MacintoshOverview.html)