# Coding the Mandelbrot Set for Beginners

Tags: plotting, complex, fractals, iteration

I'm new to Mathematica and will need some help in coding the Mandelbrot set.

I don't want to use `MandelbrotSetPlot` since I want to understand the interior mechanisms of the set. I'm also not interested in speed but just want to keep it simple.

Where do I start? z=z^2+c is relatively simple but:

- How do I make clear that the function should be iterated? I tried NestList, NestGraph and NestWhile but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to include n and n+1 instead?
- How do I make clear that c is a complex number? Can I define `c=r+i`, for example?

I found this Julia set here([Why is this Mandelbrot set's implementation infeasible: takes a massive amount of time to do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21714/why-is-this-mandelbrot-sets-implementation-infeasible-takes-a-massive-amount-o)) which makes sense to me:

```
ArrayPlot[Table[
  NestWhile[#^2 - (0. - 1 I) & , r + i I, Abs[#] < 2.0 &, 1, 10],
  {r, -2, 2, 0.005},
  {i, -2, 2, 0.005}]]
```

But a Mandelbrot should have a variable c instead, that's right?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: Just change `0. - 1 I` to `(r + i I)`. Mandelbrot is $z_{n+1}\leftarrow z_n^2 + c$ where $c$ is the intial $z_0$ - also switch your {r,...} and {i,...} ranges in the table over to rotate it by 90*. And consider using `ParallelTable` for better performance.

Comment: _How do I make clear that the function should be iterated? ... Is there a way to include n and n+1 instead?_ You're on the right track using `NestWhile` and this is the most efficient and expressive approach to this problem. There is no need to refer to `n` and `n+1` and you should continue to experiment with constructs like `Nest`, `FixedPoint`, `Map`, as you learn _Mathematica_. Also if you have any syntax trouble, these answers are a good place to start https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like

```
f[c_, maxiter_Integer : 10^4] := 
  Abs[NestWhile[#^2 + c &, 0, Abs[#] < 2 &, 1, maxiter]] < 2

f[0]
(*    True    *)

f[1]
(*    False    *)

f[I]
(*    True    *)

f[I, 10^6]
(*    True    *)

ArrayPlot[
  Table[Boole[f[N[x + I y], 10^3]], {y, -2, 2, 1/50}, {x, -2, 2, 1/50}]]
```

[image]

By playing with the working precision of `N` you can achieve high-precision calculations.

```
ArrayPlot[
  Table[Boole[f[N[x + I y], 200]],
        {y, 0.14, 0.15, 10^-5},
        {x, -0.75, -0.74, 10^-5}]]
```

[image]